# How to set wix property in custom action of vbs?

Tags: wix

I need to check if C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime*.dll exist before any other custom actions written by QT c++.

```
        <CustomAction Id="prechecksystem" Script="vbscript" Execute="deferred" Return="check">
            <![CDATA[
                Dim fso, sys32
                Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                '0:WindowsFolder, 1:SystemFolder, 2:TemporaryFolder'
                Set sys32 = fso.GetSpecialFolder(1)

                If fso.FileExists(sys32 & "\vcruntime140.dll") Then
                  Session.Property("HSRSUPPORTVCRUNTIME") = "true"
                End If
            ]]>
        </CustomAction>

        <Property Id="HSRSUPPORTVCRUNTIME" Value="false" />

        <InstallUISequence>
            <Custom Action="prechecksystem" After="CostFinalize"></Custom>
            <Show Dialog="VcruntimeNotSupportWarning" Sequence="501"> <![CDATA[ ( HSRSUPPORTVCRUNTIME="false" ) ]]> </Show>
            ...
        <InstallUISequence/>
```

But msiexec says that variable HSRSUPPORTVCRUNTIME was not defined?

Comment: You don't need ab custom action to do this and definitely should not user VBScript. Use FileSesrch.

Comment: FileSesrch works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom action to do this and definitely should not use VBScript. Use [FileSearch element](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/reference/schema/wxs/filesearch/).